# How to create SliverAppBar with custom app bar and image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create an app, where I use SliverAppBar with my CustomAppBar, but I also want to do this with the background image.

Result image

[image: img_result]

After scroll, the result must be

[image: img_result_after_scroll]

But I don't now, how to do this. Please, help me.

My code:

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Image.network(
          "image url",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
      ),
      SliverList(
        // Use a delegate to build items as they're scrolled on screen.
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          Container() // some content
        ]),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: to change the color when scrolling with scrollcontroller check this link https://gist.github.com/ianldgs/794884d8837b83fd9c64e06d9b90af4e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this out,let me know if it is working for you,also to change color  you need to listen scrolling then change the custom color

**PS**: To use custom image replace `FlutterLogo` with your image

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              expandedHeight: 160.0,
              flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 28.0,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50'),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Also there is simple workaround to change the color use `background color ` in `SliverAppBar` and use  `CachedNetworkImage`  in the background  within  the  flexibleSpace.But if you have only this design you can use this otherwise you have use scrollController, The problem for this is it will show the color of appbar as green if the image is take time to load it will show green until the image is load so that's why you have to use cacheimge pacakge,with the pacakage you can show progress indictor until the image is load to the widget@Slava

Comment: I have an issue, I've been using a custom app bar, because I could change padding in AppBar, but now I cannot, how to fix it? When i change actions padding, it changes their height to small value

Comment: can you show the code and screenshot... ? befor that try remove padding from actions if that doesn't work @Slava

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to below code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _pinned = true;
  bool _snap = false;
  bool _floating = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: _pinned,
            snap: _snap,
            floating: _floating,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
              background: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
         
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: OverflowBar(
         //   alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('pinned'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _pinned = val;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _pinned,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('snap'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _snap = val;
                        // Snapping only applies when the app bar is floating.
                        _floating = _floating || _snap;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _snap,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('floating'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _floating = val;
                        _snap = _snap && _floating;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _floating,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But this code doesn't contain the CustomAppBar, I want to change flutter SliverAppBar to my custom solution (second image)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              snap: true,
              actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(opacity: 0.0),
              flexibleSpace: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://content.presspage.com/uploads/2658/c800_logo-stackoverflow-square.jpg?98978",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverPadding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              sliver: SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black87,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                      Tab(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
                        text: "Tab 2",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          height: 700,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine, however, I want to use an AppBar that I've shown you on the second image

Comment: @Slava, use flexibleSpace with a Row, containing a Icon, background color (Container with parent of the Row) and the Container with image and borderRadius :D

Comment: But background image is visible when i scroll, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know exactly friend, do the test; is the best option