# Flutter sliver persistent

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have the code below, which I shortened as much as possible to make it easier to deal with. I want to scroll down to show the default appBar, not the background. I did some solutions, but it didn't work. Switch between them with a smooth motion.

I want to use the same existing code because I built on it.

I have attached an illustration of the problem

[image]

The main code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true, delegate: SliverHeaderDelegateComponent(expandedHeight: 300)),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  height: 1000,
                  color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Body')),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The SliverHeaderDelegateComponent code :

```
class SliverHeaderDelegateComponent extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  const SliverHeaderDelegateComponent({required this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final appBarSize = expandedHeight - shrinkOffset;
    final proportion = 2 - (expandedHeight / appBarSize);
    final percent = proportion < 0 || proportion > 1 ? 0.0 : proportion;
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) => SizedBox(
        height: expandedHeight + expandedHeight / 2,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 500,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/cmsdata/slideshow/3662115/baby-driver-rory-hi-res.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            PositionedDirectional(
              start: 0.0,
              end: 0.0,
              top: appBarSize > 0 ? appBarSize : 0,
              bottom: -100,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: percent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30 * percent),
                  child: const Card(
                    elevation: 20.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Widget"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight + expandedHeight / 2;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468773/13431819

Comment: I want to apply the required on SliverPersistentHeader and not SliverAppBar

Comment: If you can help me I will be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution using `SliverHeaderDelegateComponent` as you requested.
In this example, the `AppBar` is shown when collapsed, but you can uncomment the commented part if you want to show it on expand. (**UPDATE:** improved fading as requested in the comment section)

```
class SliverHeaderDelegateComponent extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  const SliverHeaderDelegateComponent({required this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final deadline = (expandedHeight + minExtent);
    double percent = shrinkOffset > deadline ? 1 : shrinkOffset / deadline;
    final appBarSize = expandedHeight - shrinkOffset;
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) => SizedBox(
        height: expandedHeight + expandedHeight / 2,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            // shrinkOffset == 0 // if you want to show it on expand
            shrinkOffset > expandedHeight + minExtent // show it on collapse
                ? AppBar(title: Text('App Bar'))
                : Container(
                    height: 500,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                            'https://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/cmsdata/slideshow/3662115/baby-driver-rory-hi-res.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
            PositionedDirectional(
              start: 0.0,
              end: 0.0,
              top: appBarSize > 0 ? appBarSize : 0,
              bottom: -100,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 1 - percent,
                // opacity: percent < 0.5 ? 1 : (1 - percent) * 2, // if you want to start fading when reach half way scroll
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30 * percent),
                  child: const Card(
                    elevation: 20.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Widget"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight + expandedHeight / 2;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: My friend, thank you for your help, I want to ask you another question

Comment: How can I control the opacity using the percent variable? I am the one who understands how this was calculated exactly, because whenever I try to change it, it does not work properly

Comment: I want when I get closer to the end of the scroll, the widget disappears gradually, not from the middle, it starts to disappear as in the code

Comment: @Mohammed I have updated my answer to fix the fading of your widget, check it out. The commented part starts fading when the scroll reaches halfway if you want to delay it.

Comment: yes, i see that, thank you pro